# How to find the last time an AWS resource was used?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to build a tool which tracks unused AWS resources. I have figured out how to obtain a list of all resources on my AWS account. Now, for each of these resources, I need to find out the last time it was used.

Is there some AWS API/CLI using which I can find the required info?

I did some search, but the most common suggestion I get is to use tools like Janitor Monkey and Cloud Custodian. I am trying to build a tool of my own, and do not want to employ some other software.

Comment: The answer here is going to depend on the service. Something like SQS or SES is fairly trivial. Figuring out if an EC2 instance is used tends to be be more complicated.

Comment: This is a complex challenge and it depends on what you mean by "used". You can leverage CloudWatch Metrics for some resources but they won't give you a yes/no answer. You can use S3 Access Logs and CloudTrail API Logging to learn about resource usage at some level (access to S3 objects, platform API requests like SQS, SNS). One thing to consider is to actually push this down to the relevant teams who manage the resources - leverage their current knowledge of their part of the platform to understand resource candidates that are potentially underutilized.

Comment: @mrpandey What do you mean by "last time it was used"? How would you apply this test against an Amazon RDS database or an Amazon EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

you can use AWS [Cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) for monitoring.

You can monitor metrics like CPU utilization and network latency.

Also, you can try using the logs but that will depend on the application that is running in your machine.